# newline-and-indent from CSS Mode put indent to kill ring

Tags: css, emacs

I'm using css mode 0.11 by Lars Marius Garshol, it have a function `newline-and-indent` which call  `cssm-indent-line` and it put spaces from indentation to kill ring. When I copy some css rule to clipboard and then type enter after semicolon and press <kbd>CTRL+Y</kbd> it insert spaces instead of the rule I had in clipboard.

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: Emacs comes with its own css-mode, which has many improvements over Lars's.  If there's a feature in Lars's css-mode that you miss in Emacs's, please ask for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just substitute `kill-region` by `delete-region` in `cssm-indent-line`. You could inform Lars Marius Garshol about that.